# Database doesn't connect in Kohana 3

Tags: php, kohana-3, kohana-orm

I'm trying to connect to my database in Kohana 3 but it's not connecting.

This is the query I'm trying to run from one of my modules:

```
$results = DB::select()->from('users')->where('verified', '=', 0)->execute();
```

Here's [the dump of the error](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=j7e2v8&s=7):

```
ErrorException [ Notice ]: Undefined property: Config_File::$default
MODPATH\database\classes\kohana\database.php [67]
if($config === NULL)
{
    // Load the configuration for this database
    // echo "<pre>";
    //die(print_r(unserialize(Kohana::config('database'))));
    $config = Kohana::config('database')->$name;
}

if(!isset($config['type']))
{
   throw new Kohana_Exception('Database type not defined in :name configuration',
```

I have the following config setup in application/config/database.php

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct access allowed.');
return array
(
    'default' => array
    (
        'type'       => 'mysql',
        'connection' => array(
            /**
             * The following options are available for MySQL:
             *
             * string   hostname     server hostname, or socket
             * string   database     database name
             * string   username     database username
             * string   password     database password
             * boolean  persistent   use persistent connections?
             *
             * Ports and sockets may be appended to the hostname.
             */
            'hostname'   => 'localhost',
            'database'   => 'test',
            'username'   => 'root',
            'password'   => FALSE,
            'persistent' => FALSE,
        ),
        'table_prefix' => '',
        'charset'      => 'utf8',
        'caching'      => FALSE,
        'profiling'    => TRUE,
    ),
    'alternate' => array(
        'type'       => 'pdo',
        'connection' => array(
            /**
             * The following options are available for PDO:
             *
             * string   dsn         Data Source Name
             * string   username    database username
             * string   password    database password
             * boolean  persistent  use persistent connections?
             */
            'dsn'        => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test',
            'username'   => 'root',
            'password'   => FALSE,
            'persistent' => FALSE,
        ),
        /**
         * The following extra options are available for PDO:
         *
         * string   identifier  set the escaping identifier
         */
        'table_prefix' => '',
        'charset'      => 'utf8',
        'caching'      => FALSE,
        'profiling'    => TRUE,
    ),
);
```

I'm using XAMPP 1.7.4 on Windows XP with PHP 5.3.3

Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Others pages that don't connect are fine though?

Comment: show `var_dump(Kohana::config('database'))` result

Answer (score 1):

Seems like Kohana cannot find the config file at all... Usually this file is at /modules/database/config/database.php

Comment: I don't think it's the case. The Kohana site and other blogs suggest to copy the modules/database/config/datatbase.php to application/config/database.php and that's what i did. Btw, i also copied the config in the modules/database/config folder too but no luck.